# import error: No module named Pandas Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas

I have Python2 and Python3 both installed in my laptop. I am trying to run pandas in Jupyter Notebook, but it shows an error message saying:

```
No module named 'pandas'
```

I have tried to install pandas in both python2 and python3 using:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

and

```
conda install pandas
```

both methods successfully installed the package but when I tried to import pandas, it shows the Error message again. I then tried:

```
!pip3 install pandas
```

but then it shows:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\fusuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.14.0)
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Try using `python3 -m pip install packagename` instead. Worked for me when I had a very similar issue.

Comment: Don’t capitalize the P

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I actually tried both pandas and Pandas, and neither worked. But I will edit my question to clarify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is case sensitive. No module named 'Pandas' doesn't mean there is no module 'pandas'. Try: `import pandas as pd`. Besides that I wonder that `conda install pandas` was working, since your Python paths don't look like an Anaconda installation. However, if you're using conda, you first need to `conda activate` an environment before you can use it.

Comment: I tried both pandas and Pandas, and neither of them worked.

Comment: Also, I am  working in Jupyter Notebook using the Kernel of Python3. And I don't think Jupyter Notebook will allow me to use conda activate. I did activate a Python3 environment in conda prompt, and that didn't help.

Comment: You have to launch the notebook *within* your `conda` environment.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I did that in my Conda environment, and I guess there was something wrong with Jupyter notebook. So I re-installed Python3 and Anaconda and the problem was solved. Thanks so the help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here.
I realize that I was trying to run the script without write python before the name script.
Beginners mistake... at least on my case

Comment: This is potentially a useful addition to the accepted answer. However, to make it really useful, a little bit more detail could be added, such as how you started the script to make sure the correct version of Python is executed etc.